# Join videos through concatenation

Tags: video, file-formats, conversion

Which video format allows concatenation simply by joining files?

```
cat out1.mp4 ou2.mp4 >out.mp4
```

These videos are created from images using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i image.png -s 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -t 30 -y out.mp4
```

If you can give me a running example it'd be great.

Comment: what does this have to do with signal processing?

Comment: It uses ffmpeg, and to be able to save processing/computational time I'm asking about suitable codecs to be used in ffmpeg. (x264, mjpeg,..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [FFmpeg FAQ](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Concatenating-using-the-concat-protocol-_0028file-level_0029):

> A few multimedia containers (MPEG-1, MPEG-2 PS, DV) allow to
>   concatenate video by merely concatenating the files containing them.

Hence you may concatenate your multimedia files by first transcoding them to these privileged formats, then using cat command (or copy under Windows), and finally transcoding back to your format of choice.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.avi -qscale:v 1 intermediate1.mpg
ffmpeg -i input2.avi -qscale:v 1 intermediate2.mpg
cat intermediate1.mpg intermediate2.mpg > intermediate_all.mpg
ffmpeg -i intermediate_all.mpg -qscale:v 2 output.avi
```

Comment: If I want to keep image quality, I have to use mpeg with high bitrate which both create big intermediate files and time consuming. Which settings should I choose to save processing time?